# How do you assign random variables to elements in an array of a user specified size?

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, variables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHV5K.png)if i have a vector (n,1), where 'n' is a user specified number.

how can i assign a variable to each element of the vector randomly or at least uniquely in a 'for' or 'while'loop using **MATLAB**.

My aim is to give a symbolic answer to each of the variables in a system of linear equations which i have  used the 'MATLAB rref()' function to convert the equations into a solvable form.

I know i have to do this in symbolic form.

E.g n=10 variable vector (10,1), requires 10 unique variables which are selected by the computer.

This question is also open to best alternatives!

Thanks

Comment: First of all, `rand(n,1)` gives you a uniform-distribution random vector. In order to solve your question, please show a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **First Method:**

The easiest way is to use the command `sym` itself.

```
n = 7;
A = sym('A',[1 n])

A =

[ A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7]
```

This lets you to perform symbolic operations on the symbols:

```
>> A(1)+A(2)-A(5)

ans =

A1 + A2 - A5
```

there are other ways to generate unique variables though.

---

### **Second Method:**

Just use the `genvarname` function. given the `n` number of variables you want, first define a fixed part of the variable as a cell. Here I have chosen `A`. Then use `repmat` to make a bunch of them and then use `genvarname` to generate unique variable names.

```
n = 10;
oneVar = {'A'};
Vars = repmat(oneVar,1,n);
uniqueVars = genvarname(Vars)


uniqueVars =

  1×10 cell array

    'A'    'A1'    'A2'    'A3'    'A4'    'A5'    'A6'    'A7'    'A8'    'A9'
```

---

### **Third Method:**

Since `genvarname` is going to be removed from the next release of MATLAB, as suggested, you can use the following functions:

```
n = 5;
S = repmat({'B'},1,n);
N = matlab.lang.makeValidName(S);
U = matlab.lang.makeUniqueStrings(N,{},namelengthmax);
```

So here, you have `n` the number of variables you want and then make the main part of the variable (`B` here) and repeat it `n` times. And then use `makeValidName` and `makeUniqueStrings` out of them.

```
U =

  1×5 cell array

    'B'    'B_1'    'B_2'    'B_3'    'B_4'
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It works perfectly except that i can't seem to multiply the variable vector produced with a vector full of numbers. I've tried to change the vector to symbolic form  using sym U and sym(U)  but symbolic vector multiplication doesn't work.

Comment: As also pointed out by others, your question is not clear. you should provide a minimal example that shows what you expect.

Comment: Apologies NKN, i only just properly acknowledged and understood your first method.